Interpreting a field strength vs distance graph

The graph above is taken from my IB physics curriculum and is showing the electrical field strength vs distance for a negative charge.
I am wondering whether this is showing that the field strength is increasing or decreasing with distance. I have asked multiple people on this and I have gotten mixed answers.
Some argue that because the magnitude of the values are decreasing with distance, the field strength is decreasing with distance.
Other people I asked said that the field strength is actually increasing since the values are getting bigger with distance(closer to zero).
I am unsure which one is the correct interpretation but I am thinking that conceptually the first explanation makes more sense. It would make sense that if you're further away from the negative charge that you would "feel" less of it.
I would appreciate some confirmation on this manner. Thank you for your understanding.

I'd say the field value is increasing and the strength is decreasing (for my taste, "strength" is more related to the magnitude, regardless of the sign).

So from this graph the field strength is indeed decreasing right? Also what would be the meaning of the "field value" in this context?

It must be a measurement of the field in some direction, I presume. If, for example, it is the vertical component, than the graph means that it starts with a strong negative value (the field pointing downward) and later becomes less negative (still pointing  downward, but weaker). Without further context the actual meaning cannot be deduced.

that makes perfect sense thank you!

@JosBergervoet you should really turn those comments into an answer instead.

OK, it is now an answer.

I'd say the field value is increasing and the strength is decreasing (for my taste, "strength" is more related to the magnitude, regardless of the sign).
Looking at the graph, we can only presume that it is a measurement of the field in some direction, i.e. some specific field component. If, for example, it is the vertical component, then the graph means that it starts with a strong negative value (the field pointing downward) and later becomes less negative (still pointing downward, but weaker).
But that is just an example of what could be meant, without further context the actual meaning cannot be deduced.
